# Overriding constructor`s result via Proxy

Tags: javascript, typescript, proxy

I`m trying to create a service implementing 2 interfaces: Getters and Setters. I implement the latter directly in class and proxy the former`s methods into a private member of the class:

```
class PublicService {
  constructor(getters) {
    this.getters = getters;

    return new Proxy(this, {
      get(target, prop, receiver) {
        if (prop in target) {
          return Reflect.get(target, prop, receiver);
        } else {
          return Reflect.get(target.getters, prop, receiver);
        }
      }
    })
  }

  save() {
    console.log('WOHOOOAAA!!! It`s alive');
  }
}
```

This works fine. But I need to type it with typescript. And this is the trouble point: I can`t made the class to understand result type of the constructor:

```
interface SetService {
    save(): void,
}
interface GetService {
    getById(id: number): string,
}


class PublicService implements SetService, GetService {
  constructor(private getters: GetService) {
    return new Proxy(this, {
      get(target, prop, receiver) {
        if (prop in target) {
          return Reflect.get(target, prop, receiver);
        } else {
          return Reflect.get(target.getters, prop, receiver);
        }
      }
    })
  }

  save() {
    console.log('WOHOOOAAA!!! It`s alive');
  }
}
```

It fails with error: `Class 'PublicService' incorrectly implements interface 'GetService'. Property 'getById' is missing in type 'PublicService' but required in type 'GetService'.`

Actually I`m looking for any way to reach my goal: Get the service with both setters and getters correctly typed methods.

Comment: Tbh, you probably shouldn't be using proxies here.

Comment: @Bergi why not? it works ok without types... what is an alternative way?

Comment: It's pretty overcomplicated, and actually doesn't work if the `getById` method uses `this`. Why not just drop the proxy and write a `getById(id) { return this.getters.getById(id); }` method for `PublicService`?

Comment: @Bergi
`and actually doesn't work if the getById method uses this.` - it\`s ok for this case
`Why not just drop the proxy and write a...` - I don\`t wanna manually redirect all getters - it\`a pretty overcomplicated =)

Comment: Well, TypeScript will only work for explicitly spelt out methods.